# Using preg_match to expand abbreviations

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to use a `preg_match` expression in php to return common abbreviations and then replace them with the full version of the word (i.e. "St." becomes "Street") before adding them to a database.

This means it needs to match whitespace before the abbreviation, the full abbreviation, optional ".", and either the end of the string or whitespace (so as to not return a match for "Station"). I've tried:

```
preg_match( "#\s(S|s)t\.?\s#" , $my_string , $matches )
preg_match( "#(\s(S|s)t\.?)+(\s|$)+#" , $my_string , $matches )
preg_match( "#(\s{1}(S|s){1}t{1}\.?){1}\s{1}#" , $my_string , $matches )
```

I'm getting matches I don't expect and not sure why. 
When `$my_string = "My St. and something else"`.:

the 1st $matches: `array ( " St." , "S" )`

the 2nd: `array ( " St." , " St." , "S", " " )`

the 3rd: `array ( " St.", " St." , "S" )`

It returns the corresponding matches in case "St." is replaced with "st.", "St", or "st.".

How do I narrow the matches to only a single instance in these cases?

Functionally the corresponding replacement seems to work because it replaces only the first match, but I feel like I should be able to narrow to a single match.

And a secondary question, in the second `preg_match()` above I try using `(\s|$)` for whitespace or the end of the string -- is this acceptable, if not, how should this be done?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Bolaho/1 (`/(?<=\s)([Ss]t\.?)\s/`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do [this](https://regex101.com/r/Bolaho/1):

```
 preg_match( "#(?<=\s)([Ss]t\.?)\s#" , $my_string , $matches );
```

the first element of the array $matches will have "St. " (the full match), and the second element will have "St.", the part you want to replace.

If you rather match the preceding blank and avoid the trailing one:

```
preg_match( "#(\s[Ss]t\.?)(?>\s)#" , $my_string , $matches );
```

You can see the second one working [here](https://regex101.com/r/mBAwl5/2).

Well, for completeness sake, I'd do something more or less like this:

```
$patterns     = [];
$replacements = [];
$string       = "The St. Leicester Square is near a statue located somewhere.
The train left the St";

$patterns[]     = "#(?<=\s)([Ss]t\.?)(?=\s|$)#m";
$replacements[] = "station";

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```

Which you can see the whole thing working [here](https://repl.it/FMFn/2).

Comment: That link to the debugger and tester is super useful!  Thanks.  But the match I'm looking for is " St. " or " St." (if end of string).  Probably easier to specify the replacement is " Street".   So I'm thinking I might want a lookahead so as to not match the trailing space, and remove the lookbehind?
Also, that returns 2 matches...but is this not a problem?  The first match always seems to be the longest.

Comment: like this maybe: `#(\s[Ss]t\.?)(?=\s)#`
edit: Nope, still two matches

Comment: Ah, got it!  I actually used `#(?<=\s)([Ss]t\.?)(?=\s)#` and used "Street" rather than " Street" as replacement.  Also, I just read that two matches is normal behavior.

Comment: One last one.  To get the whitespace OR end of string, and to match an optional ",":
`#(?<=\s)([Ss]t\.?\,?)(?=\s|$)#`

Comment: No need.  My previous post is the expression that answers my question.

Comment: completed the answer anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using negative lookarounds:

```
/(?<!\S)st\.?(?!\S)/i
```

This way you don't need to match any whitespaces around the part you need to replace:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?<!\S)st\.?(?!\S)/i', 'Street', $str);
```